# Don't COUNTIF second cell is inactive

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I am trying to create an Google sheet formula that will count the occurrences of instruments from one table into another table - **only if the instrument is "Inactive"**

[image]

I haven't found a way to include the "Inactive" criteria.
This is the formula I have tried to put into the `F5` cell, but I only get an `#ERROR!`

```
=COUNTIFS(B5:B20;E5,C5:C20;"<>Inactive")
```

**Is my desired outcome achievable using this exact setup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$5:B20,E5,$C$5:C20,"<>Inactive")
```

[image]

Comment: How is this different to what the OP has already tried?

Comment: He Mentioned the `;` instead of `,` in his formula.

Comment: Ah ok... but you have only changed the `;` after C20. Did you intend to leave the one after B20?

Comment: Yeah now i tested it.